# ffmpeg either dropping frames or writing invalid PTS timestamps: Bug or my mistake?

Tags: ffmpeg, framerate, bug, m2ts

I have noticed that ffmpeg sometimes writes invalid PTS timestamps when using `-t` on a M2TS input. Is this my mistake or is it a bug in ffmpeg?

**Steps to reproduce:**

Download [this M2TS file](https://www.dwsamplefiles.com/?dl_id=314) and save it as `1.m2ts`. This file contains one video stream with `25 fps` (that is, one video frame takes exactly `0.04 s` (`40 ms`)) and one audio stream that isn't interesting for the purpose of this post.

Open the terminal, navigate into the directory that contains the file, and execute the following command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i 1.m2ts -codec copy -map 0 -t 2 2.m2ts
```

Now examine the output file, `2.m2ts`, and observe that the latest video frame's PTS is `3.560`, and that the PTS of the previous video frame is `3.480`.

This obviously is wrong. After the frame at `3.480`, the next frame should be presented at `3.520`, not `3.560`. Either ffmpeg has dropped the video frame that should come at `3.520`, or it has written a wrong PTS to the last video frame (`3.560` instead of `3.520`).

Of course, when talking about "last" or "before", I am referring to the order of the frames in time (more precisely, I have ordered the video frames by PTS), not the order of the frames in the file.

**Question:**

Is this a bug in ffmpeg, or is there a mistake in my command above?

**ffmpeg version:**

`ffmpeg version 2024-01-14-git-34a47b97de-full_build-www.gyan.dev` on Windows 10 x64 Enterprise

**Further remarks:**

I have noticed the problem with several of my M2TS files; I don't have the time to test other formats. Unfortunately, I cannot provide my files for download. That's the reason why I have linked to another file.

In other words: The problem is not specific for the file I have linked. Rather, I have encountered it with various video frame rates and audio tracks in various M2TS files from different sources.

I didn't investigate the audio tracks with respect to similar gaps yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This not a bug, just a result of B-frames dependency.

The video stream has has 3 types of frames:

- I-Frame - not dependent on any frame.
- P-Frame - dependent only on frames before it.
- B-Frame - dependent on frames before and on frames after the encoded frame.

The last encoded video frame that matches 2 seconds duration is a **B-Frame**.
The first frame in 2.m2ts has `pts_time=1.48`.
The last frame in 2.m2ts supposed to have `pts_time=3.48`.

Since the frame with `pts_time=3.48` is a B-Frame, it depends on the P-Frame that encoded after it.
The P-Frame that comes after has `pts_time=3.56`.
Without that P-Frame, it is impossible to decode the B-Frame, so the muxer keeps that last extra P-Frame.

---

Analyzing the video frames using FFprobe:

We may use FFprobe for getting the pts_time and pict_type of the video streams of the 2 files.

`ffprobe -select_streams v -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries frame=pts_time,pict_type 1.m2ts > 1.txt`

`ffprobe -select_streams v -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries frame=pts_time,pict_type 2.m2ts > 2.txt`

Comparing the files using comparing tool, gives the following result:

```
1.txt       2.txt
------      ------

1.480000    1.480000
I           I
...
B           B
3.040000    3.040000
B           B
3.080000    3.080000
P           P
3.120000    3.120000
B           B
3.160000    3.160000
B           B
3.200000    3.200000
B           B
3.240000    3.240000
P           P
3.280000    3.280000
B           B
3.320000    3.320000
B           B
3.360000    3.360000
B           B
3.400000    3.400000
P           P
3.440000    3.440000
B           B
3.480000    3.480000
B           B
3.520000    
B           
3.560000    3.560000
P           P
```

Note that the B-Frame with `pts_time=3.52` is not required for decoding `3.48` (`3.48` is dependent on the `3.56` P-Frame but not on that `3.52` B-Frame), so `3.52` is skipped.

Comment: Thank you very much for the excellent explanation, accepted and +1. Now I understand why I have seen that "problem" only at the end of the output file. By the way, the reason for asking is that I plan to concatenate M2TS files using the concat demuxer, so I investigated the timestamps at the end of the first file. Seems that it will get complicated. What happens if I want to append a M2TS file whose first video frame PTS is `3.52`? I guess that's not possible then, because the last PTS of the first segment is `3.56` while the first two PTS of the second segment would be `3.52` and `3.56`.

Comment: I am not sure... It is recommended to split the video stream only in full GOPs (start with an I-Frame, and end one frame before an I-frame). When splitting a file using `segment` muxer, I think it's possible to split in non I-Frame, and use concat demuxer for merging, and getting back the original stream. When using `-t 2`, I guess it's not going to work.